# What is behind this empirically observed property of gcd's and partitions of a finite set of distinct primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So here's something interesting.  Consider a set of odd primes $p_1...p_m$  Consider the gcd of the m products $(p_i-1)(\bar p_{j\ne i}-1)$.  Call that $D_1$.  Now consider the gcd of the $m \choose 2$ products $(p_ip_j-1)(\bar p_{k\ne i,j}-1)$.  Call that $D_2$.  For m odd, it appears to be true empirically (based on millions of samples) that $D_1=D_2$ (almost all of the time), $D_1 \mid D_2$ (most of the rest), $D_2 \mid D_1$ (what's left), but never gcd$(D_1,D_2) \ne D_1$ or $D_2$.  Why does that last case never occur for m odd?

Here's my data.  Note the trends as well.  Any insights?  Counterexamples to show my code is buggy?  All $D_i$ constructed in this way must be multiples of 4, but that alone can't explain what I'm seeing.

[image]

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You'll probably want to learn some basic `MathJax` and $\LaTeX$ syntax to express your ideas more clearly.  See this [introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I'm actually pretty good with LaTex, didn't know it was supported here.  I do now, so thanks!  --BF

Comment: One thought:  As $m$ increases, the GCD becomes smaller and smaller, closer to the minimum, so the odds that they are identical or divide one another increase.

Comment: Why are there $m$ products $(p_i-1)(p_j-1)$? As $i,j$ run through $(1..m)$, there should be $\binom{m}2$.

Comment: Sorry, that's my LaTex laziness. For m=4, there are ${4 \choose 1}$ = 4 products for $D_1:  (p_1-1)(p_2p_3p_4-1),(p_2-1)(p_1p_3p_4-1),(p_3-1)(p_1p_2p_4-1),(p_4-1)(p_1p_2p_3-1)$.  For $D_2$, there are ${4 \choose 2} =6$ products, but half are redundant so we only need 3:  $(p_1p_2-1)(p_3p_4-1),(p_1p_3-1)(p_2p_4-1),(p_1p_4-1)(p_2p_3-1)$.  I tried to make this a little clearer by adding a bar over the $p_{j \ne 1}$ term above.

Comment: ^$p_{j \ne i}$ term^